# Need understanding of implementation of onClick callback in android view

Tags: java, android

```
        final EditText textview = new EditText(this);
        textview.setText("Nothing to display as DB Read failed!!");
        textview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textview.setText("Stop clicking me");
            }
        });
```

Ideally build should fail since `textview` object is defined local to my `onCreate()` method and the object is not passed to `onClick()` method.

I am relatively new to Java. Could anyone explain how the object is accessible?
1 more thing.. Why do I need to pass `View v` argument and how is it useful to this method?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I believe you are asking how is it possible that, even when the `onCreate()` callback has ended, the click listener is able to call `textview.setText()`, using a reference (`textview`) created inside the callback. If this is your case, please reformat your question to make it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference to the objects of the outer class, which are accessed from inside the anonymous class, are copied via an auto-generated constructor.
But you can only access variables which are declared **final** , so they can't possibly be modified by the rest of the outer class once copied.

As for the **View v** ,  like **SimonR** said, it's a reference to the textview itself.
But you will have to cast it to TextView before calling *setText(...)*

Comment: Thanx @kushtrim!! So.. I understand that textview will become a member of the interface which can be accessed later when onClick is executed. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah a member of the anonymous inner class.

Answer (score 0):

View v is the Element, on which the OnClickListener has been attached to. You can simply change textview within the method to v.

```
v.setText("Stop clicking me");
```